# ASP.NET MVC2 and JSON model binding with validation to an action method

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-2, model-binding, validation

Phil Haack's [blog entry](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx) describes this process using ASP.NET MVC 2's futures and Crockford's [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).  John Resig also recommends using Crockford's json2.js in [this article](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/) regarding "use strict";.

To get this feature today, would you still download the MVC 2 Futures, or is this included in the MVC 2 final, or is this part of the new MVC 3 preview?

Edit:

As Per Jakub's suggestion (and Phil Haack, woot!), my script finally works.  A big appreciation to both of them.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    var myData = {};
    myData.value = '9/14/2010 12:00:00 AM';
    var myJson = JSON.stringify(myData);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/AdSketch/GetPrintProducts",
        data: myJson, 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The MVC controller code:

```
public JsonResult GetPrintProducts(string value)
{   // At this point "value" holds "9/14/2010 12:00:00 AM"
    return Json(value);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For MVC2 you need Futures. Get the dll, add reference to it and in Global.asax add (Application_Start):

```
ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new JsonValueProviderFactory());
```

Don't know about MVC3 - I'm waiting for an RTM.
But I do encourage you to give it a go, as sending JSON up to Actions is a pure bliss ;-)

Comment: As a comment to Jakub's comment, this is totally built into MVC3 out of the box, and it works fabulous!

Answer (score 2):

In MVC 3 there is *ValueProviderFactories* provided out of the box.